# scientific-like notation with more than 1 digit before the point

Tags: python, python-2.7, scientific-notation

Is the any way in python to make a string out of a number which performs like this:

- raw number: 30.0123456789

  - result: 30.0123
- raw number: 0.0123456789

  - result: 12.3457e-3
- raw number: 0.000123456789

  - result: 12.3457e-5
- raw number: 12345.67891011

  - result: 12.3457e3

In that case it would be always 4 decimals after the decimal point (filled with zeros if applicable)

It would always also be 2 numbers before the decimal point

Comment: '%.4E' % (number)

Comment: and multiple variations of it

Comment: none succeeded...

Comment: `E` constructs scientific notation, which your desired output is not.

Comment: I know... but I couldn't find out how to work around it... that's why I came here for some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own format function based on scientific notation

```
def format(num,kk,cc=12):
    # kk - digits before dot , cc - digits after dot
    fmt = '{0:.'+str(kk+cc-1)+'e}'
    ss = fmt.format(num);
    s1 = ss.replace('.','')
    p1 = s1.split('e')
    a1 = p1[0]
    a2 = int(p1[1])
    return '{0}.{1}e{2}'.format(a1[0:kk],a1[kk:],a2-kk+1)
```

For convenience you can create an object with custom format:

```
class MyNum:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
    def __format__(self,fmt):
        args = fmt.split('.')
        a1 = int(args[0]) if len(args) > 0 else 1
        a2 = int(args[1]) if len(args) > 1 else 6
        return format(self.value,a1,a2)
```

Now, you can use it in format:

```
print('{0:3.6}'.format(MyNum(25.123456789)))
#print 251.234568e-1
```

Comment: @zephyr , You are right. added digits before dot and digits after dot,

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`math.log10`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.log10) and a formula which seems to fit your examples (more tests are neeeded):

```
from math import log10, ceil
numbers = [30.0123456789, 0.0123456789, 0.000123456789, 12345.67891011]

n = 2
for number in numbers:
    e = ceil(log10(number) - n)
    n_digits = number * 10**-e
    if e:
        print('%.4fe%d' % (n_digits, e))
    else:
        print('%.4f' % number)

#   30.0123
#   12.3457e-3
#   12.3457e-5
#   12.3457e3
```

As a bonus, it should work with any `n`. With `n=3`:

```
300.1235e-1
123.4568e-4
123.4568e-6
123.4568e2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's no built-in float formatting that will do this, but it's simple enough to fake: convert 1/10 of the number to normal scientific notation, then move the decimal place over by one...

```
def unscientific_notation(n):
    rv = "%.5e" % (n / 10.0)
    rv = rv[0] + rv[2] + rv[1] + rv[3:]     # x.yz -> xy.z
    if rv.endswith("e+00"):    # handle 10..99 as specified
        rv = rv[:-4]
    return rv
```

There may need to be an additional special case for numbers in the 1..9 range - displaying `5` as `50e-1` seems like it might not be the desired result.